# Gitlab CI/CD detect file modification to choose stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Let's admit three distinct folders in my git repository. Each one of them is containing some code that I want to test, but each in a different manner, so I want to make a `gitlab ci/cd pipeline` with a different stage for each one of them.

In order to save some GitLab runner time, and to accelerate the process, I would like to detect in which folders have been made the new commits, so that I can execute only the stages where some code have changed.

Is there a way to implement such a behavior?

Comment: For me, the correct configuration should be to set the same stage, let's say `test`, and have 3 different jobs with `rules: if: changes:`

Comment: I think this should do the trick yes ! I didn't think about it. Maybe a `only: changes:` would be more readable

Comment: `rules` is the new way to express `only/except`. [Doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except) says : `only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.`

Comment: Well in that case I am glad you told me I didn't know that ! Many thanks !